# ImportError: cannot import name (not a circular dependency)

Tags: python

I have the problem on importing the class in the same package, and it seems not a circular dependency problem. So I'm really confused now.

```
my-project/
   lexer.py
   exceptions.py
```

I declared an exception in `exceptions.py` and wants to use it in `lexer.py`:

exceptions.py:

```
class LexError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, line):
        self.message = message
        self.line = line
```

and in lexer.py:

```
import re
import sys

from exceptions import LexError
...
```

It shouldn't be circular dependency since `lexer.py` is the only file has `import` in it.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you try renaming `exceptions.py` to something else and see if that helps?

Comment: @Adeeb it works!!! But why? In this [repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ValidationError) you can see that exceptions.py should cause a ImportError!?

Comment: @Adeeb This [repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ValidationError) is from the book [Flask Web Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031116.do)

Comment: in the repo, the code is using `app.exceptions` not `exceptions`. @falsetru has already pointed out that `import exceptions` will use the builtin module not the one you created.

Comment: It try to import from `exceptions` (python exeptions not yours) `LexError`.                                                                                       Renaming `exeptions.py` should resolve the problem.

Comment: @Adeeb Oh thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exceptions` conflicts with builtin module [`exception`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

```
>>> import exceptions
>>> exceptions.LexError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LexError'
>>> from exceptions import LexError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name LexError
```

Use different module name.